# Getting undefined when trying to call a method using a factory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Trying to use composition over inheritance with factory functions in Javscript and I am getting function is not defined with the following code:

(dogIsCreated is not defined)

```
var dog = function dog(state) {
  return {
    create: function create() {
      console.log('Create the dog');
      dogIsCreated();
    },
    dogIsCreated: function dogIsCreated() {
      console.log('Ready');
    }
  }
}

var ted = dog().create();
```

Be amazing if someone could point me in the right direction? Am I using completely the wrong syntax.

Thanks :)

Comment: right there `var dog = function dog(state)`.

Comment: There is no function with name `dogIsCreated` (at least in the scope you are trying to call it from). `dogIsCreated` is a property on the object. Maybe you meant `this.dogIsCreated()` ?

Comment: @Tresdin: There is no issue in that line.

Comment: could we have an explaination why `this` is required?

Comment: this.dogIsReady() - what an imbecile I am! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the scope the `create()` method is apart of using the `this` keyword.

```
var dog = function dog(state) {
  return {
    create: function create() {
      console.log('Create the dog');
      this.dogIsCreated();
    },
    dogIsCreated: function dogIsCreated() {
      console.log('Ready');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The explanation reads a bit strange. It sounds like we have to change the visibility of `create` (which we don't).

Answer (score 1):

This (dogIsCreated)is not a global function. dogIsCreated function created with dog Object. this is object method , so you are calling this method inside another (same)object method, so we can call that method using 'this'–

```js
var dog = function dog(state) {
  return {
    create: function create() {
      console.log('Create the dog');
      this.dogIsCreated();
    },
    dogIsCreated: function dogIsCreated() {
      console.log('Ready');
    }
  }
}

var ted = dog().create();
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful. No one likes to play the "spot the difference" game.

Comment: This (dogIsCreated)is not a global function.  dogIsCreated function created with dog Object. this is object method

Comment: Basically yes. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34794268/edit) your answer to provide more information.